# Solve tan(x)+cos(x)=1/2

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible (not numerically) to find the $x$ such as:

$$
tan(x)+cos(x)=1/2
$$

?

All my tries finishes in a 4 degree polynomial. By example, calling c = cos(x):

$$
\frac{\sqrt{1-c^2}}{c}+c=\frac{1}{2}
$$

$$
\sqrt{1-c^2}+c^2=\frac{1}{2}c
$$

$$
1-c^2=c^2(\frac{1}{2}-c)^2=c^2(\frac{1}{4}-c+c^2)
$$

$$
c^4-c^3+\frac{5}{4}c^2-1=0
$$

Comment: Wolfram alpha confirms that there are no 'simple' solutions to the equation (click on exact form): https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan(x)%2Bcos(x)%3D1%2F2

Comment: Of course it is possible (cf. Ferrari's formula for the quartic, for example).

Comment: @Allawonder: this question is in a scholar book for 16 years old, I doubt the was thiking on quartics

Comment: @pasabaporaqui I was answering your question. You had said, *Is it possible...?* I answered that it was.

Comment: @Allawonder: yes, your comment is correct, I only adding context

Answer (score 1):

If we set $X=\cos x$ and $Y=\sin x$, the equation becomes
$$
Y=\frac{1}{2}X-X^2
$$
so the problem becomes intersecting the parabola with the circle $X^2+Y^2=1$.

[image]

This is generally a degree four problem. The image suggests there is no really elementary way to find the intersections.

The equation becomes
$$
X^4-X^3+\frac{5}{4}X^2-1=0
$$
as you found out. The two real roots are approximately
$$
-0.654665139167 \qquad 0.921490878816
$$
These correspond to $x=\pm2.284535877184578$ and $x=\pm0.39889463967156$, that correspond to what WolframAlpha finds.

Answer (score 0):

If we put $t=x/2$ then we get $${2\tan t\over 1-\tan ^2t} +2\cos ^2 t -1={1\over 2}$$

Let $y= \tan t$. Since $\cos ^2t = {1\over 1+y^2}$ we get $$3y^4+4y^3-4y^2+4y+1=0$$

which I'm not sure if any helps. :(